# How to interpret cell size ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, coordinate-system, resolution, units

I have a raster layer that has cell size(x, y) 0.008928, 0.008928. 
I download it from the website as 1km resolution data under WGS_84. I can not find the unit for these numbers in the metadata. Is there a proper way to calculate the cell size in meters? I need to resample them to 4km resolution data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the data that you have in WGS 84, this means that the cell size is in degree unit. In order to get the cell size in meter, you need to change the projection of your raster from WGS84 to meter projection such as UTM or any other projections that is meter unit depending of the size of the study area. To change the projection of your raster data in ArcGIS go to `ArcToolbox -> Data Management tools -> Projections and Transformations -> Raster -> Project Raster`. The [Understanding Map Projections](http://gis.icao.int/icaoetod/map_projections[1].pdf) PDF file from ESRI has detialed explanation about map projections.

Comment: So can I convert the raster to UTM, resample it to 4km and convert it back to WGS84? Then I get the resampled result back in degree units? Thank you!!

Comment: If yo are going to work in geographic, why don't you resample your raster directly in WGS 84. 1 degree is approximately 111.32 km, but this will change depending the latiude of your study area. You can refer to this Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees to ratio between degree and KM

Comment: Okay I will go on learn these pages. Thank you very much!